# Scraping english version of a japanese website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the English version of a Japanese website, the problem is that the link for the Japanese and English version are the same, is there a way to tell beautifulsoup to scrape the English version instead of the Japanese?

Link I want to scrape:

https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS02/?match_card_id=17975

Comment: https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS02/?match_card_id=17975&lang=en

Comment: If you inspect the button you would see it's not actually the same site but has and additional param of lang=en. Try passing that.

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate that adding `lang=en` url query parameter actually works:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> url = "https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS02/?match_card_id=17975"
>>> english_url = "https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS02/?match_card_id=17975&lang=en"
>>>
>>> print(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").find(class_="team-name").get_text(strip=True))
サガン鳥栖
>>> print(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(english_url).content, "html.parser").find(class_="team-name").get_text(strip=True))
Sagan Tosu
```

Note that you can also add a `SFCM01LANG` *cookie* with `en` value:

```
>>> url = "https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS02/?match_card_id=17975"
>>> response = requests.get(url, cookies={'SFCM01LANG': 'en'})
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.find(class_="team-name").get_text(strip=True)) 
Sagan Tosu
```